# add a sql query result to a class

Tags: c#, linq

im trying to add a single row to a class using linq to sql.
i have a table (AdressesTable) wich contains a key named ID and an adress1 and adress2 column...

i created a class:

```
public class Adresses
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public int adress1 { get; set; }
public int adress2 { get; set; }
}
```

i created a datacontext and wrote a query

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();

Adresses adr = (from p in db.AdressesTable 
    where p.ID ==1 
    select p).First();
```

but it's not working... how can i add a sql query result to a class object?

Comment: **How** is it 'not working'?

Comment: *what's* not working?  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Show DBDataContext class content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a `DbContext` like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
var adr = (from p in db.Addresses
    where p.ID == 1
    select p).First();
```